# How do I add administrator accounts for granting static permissions to my Azure AD App?

Tags: azure, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have set up a Azure Active Directory App so that I can access the Microsoft Graph API with MSAL. However, I want to perform API calls without a user (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) and as such I have added a few permissions that require "Admin consent" to my app. However, I cannot find a way to grant my app these permissions.

[image: Azure Portal API Permissions view]

I've tried looking around the Azure portal for a way to grant these permissions but without success. I have also tried using the https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent&... link to grant permissions, but unsucessfully so.

The response I received was

> AADSTS500201: We are unable to issue tokens from this API version for
>   a Microsoft account. Please contact the application vendor as they
>   need to use version 2.0 of the protocol to support this.

I do not have an Azure subscription (not even the free one), but seeing as I was able to add apps to Azure AD as well as get access tokens and then make API calls on behalf of the authorized users I assumed I might not need a subscription.

Comment: Okay, so there's quite a few questions here :) You don't need an Azure subscription technically to use Azure AD. To define app permissions (app roles) for service-to-service calls, you can check how to do it in my blog: https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad. You'll have to add them to the manifest in portal.azure.com. You'd need to define those on the app registration for your API, and then require them from the app registration of your client app. You can then grant admin consent through a button on the page where you define required permissions.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to show that I do not see a "grant admin consent" button from my API Permissions view on the Azure Portal. 

I would note that I am not trying to expose my own API, but instead only use this registered app as a means of making calls to Microsoft's Graph API once users authorize it and lend it permission.

Reading your blog post, I am led to believe that I should be adding my permissions to the app manifest - specifically the "oauth2Permissions" field, which contains no values for me currently. Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: Apparently when I created the app, an account admin@*myemail*com.onmicrosoft.com was created for me. I can use it to open the https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent... link and give permission, after which I was redirected to the redirect_uri set in the app. However in the API Permissions view I see no changes. It looks the same as on the picture in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made another app and now I have the grant consent button when I open the API Permissions view.